# How to make routesegment call by using $location.path() in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using routesegment provider for routing in angular. how can i make a url call using $location.path().

Code is below :

```
    FinancialGameApp.config(['$routeSegmentProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($routeSegmentProvider, $routeProvider) {

    // Configuring provider options

    $routeSegmentProvider.options.autoLoadTemplates = true;

    // Setting routes. This consists of two parts:
    // 1. `when` is similar to vanilla $route `when` but takes segment name instead of params hash
    // 2. traversing through segment tree to set it up
    $routeSegmentProvider
        .when('/Home', 's1')
        .when('/Login', 's2')
        .when('/Signup', 's3')
        .when('/UserDetails', 's4')
        .segment('s1', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/home.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .segment('s2', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .segment('s3', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/signup.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
         .segment('s4', {
             templateUrl: 'Views/UserDetailsPage.html',
             controller: 'userDetailsController'
         })
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
}]);
```

And I want to call the segment s4 through method call using $location.path()

```
 authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
        $location.path('/UserDetails');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it by adding # before the url.

```
authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
        $location.path('/#/UserDetails');
    }
```

Also, you can use segment name with `getSegmentUrl` to get the hash instead of the direct url

```
authService.login($scope.loginData).then(function (response) {
            $location.path($routeSegment.getSegmentUrl('s4'));
        }
```

Comment: Actually, `$location.path($routeSegment.getSegmentUrl('s4'))` should be enough.